# Colours of the text in R editor?

Tags: r

In my collegue's version of R the different types of text become different colours when you write in the editor(for example functions are blue while text in quotation marks is green). For me, however, all the text is black which I think makes it harder to get a quick understanding of the code. There is also no automatic line break. Is it because he has the mac version while I have the PC version? Is there som way i can change this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might like [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/). But there are many other editors that support syntax highlighting for R, e.g. Notepad++.

Comment: If you want a quick text editor with syntax highlighting in R, you can checkout my package [**rite**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rite/), otherwise find an IDE like @Roland said.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: changing the settings below will allow you to change the color of, say, R help text or of code but doesn't actually enable syntax highlighting. Per @Roland's comment, your best bet is a different text editor (such as Notepad++,RStudio, or Sublime) or a syntax highlighting package.  Apparently the Mac version of the R editor really is just better (per this [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Settings))**

You can change the settings in Edit>RGUI Preferences, under "Console and Pager Colours". 
[image: RGUI configuration Editor screen grab]

Comment: Which setting are they supposed to change in order to get syntax highlighting?

Comment: This isn't what OP is looking for, as this still treats all text as one color.

Comment: @Thomas, good point- I misunderstood. I've updated the answer.

Comment: how do I make this change permanent? It seems to reset to white everytime I reopen the same project.

Comment: How do you do it in RStudio?